# Why would bash refuse to be case-insensitive?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, tab-completion, case-sensitivity

I am working on a server where I seem to be unable to set bash to be case insensitive. I have the shell set to,

```
set completion-ignore-case on
```

But this does not seem to be working. I am working over ssh with tmux. The version of bash is,

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

running on,

```
Linux 3.16.0-77-generic #99~14.04.1-Ubuntu
```

I have looked into various /etc configuration files in the hope of finding some flag that might be causing this behavior, but I haven't seen anything odd. I am unsure how to dig in further to figure out where the problem is and would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest:

```
bind 'set completion-ignore-case on'
```

Comment: Thank you! So, if I understand correctly, this would be equivalent to if I had put 'set sompletion-ignore-case on' in an .inputrc file?

Comment: Yes, if you have a `.inputrc` try it or put `bind 'set completion-ignore-case on'` in your `.bashrc`.

Comment: @Spittin'IT: you can use `bind` to set Readline key bindings and variables.